# Subtracting two pandas dataframes with different shapes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames
df1 is like (AA is the index)

```
AA 
a  1 2 3 4 5
b  2 2 3 4 5
```

and  df2 is like (AA is the index)

```
AA 
a  10
b  20
```

output should be (all values of df1-single value of df2 at row wise matching Index column AA)

```
AA 
a  -9 -8 -7 -6 -5
b  -18 -18 -17 -16 -15
```

I tried doing the saame in many ways. Could someone in the group please help me on this? Thank you

Comment: It's hard to tell what type of data this is. They look like Series the way they're printed. Can you instead of plain text put in some code that can be used to reproduce these structures as they appear on your end?

Comment: i don't understand the structs either, can you `print(df1.to_dict())` and do the same for df2 paste it into your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apply` function to solve it.Here is the example code.

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    ], index=['a', 'b']
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [10],
        [20]
    ], index=['a', 'b']
)
# 0 is the first column index is df2
# x.name is the row index name in df1
df3 = df1.apply(lambda x :x-df2.loc[x.name,0],axis=1)
df3
```

And you will get output bellow if you run in jupyter.

[image]

If not, you should use `print(df3)` to see the output.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy in NumPy, because of its [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) rules. So you could do the calculation on the value arrays (assuming the index values are the same for both input DataFrames, as in your example) and create a new DataFrame from the result:

```py
import pandas as pd

index = pd.Index(['a', 'b'], name='AA')
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    [2, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
                   index=index)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[10],
                    [20]],
                   index=index)                   

df = pd.DataFrame(df1.values - df2.values,
                  index=index) 
df
```

```
      0   1   2   3   4
AA                  
a    -9  -8  -7  -6  -5
b   -18 -18 -17 -16 -15
```